# InvalidOperationException: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" on postback

Tags: asp.net

When I do a postback, I get this error : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Here's the stacktrace :

```
[InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding) +11470463
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +329

[HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +11584898
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +157
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm() +11585700
   System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull) +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode() +100
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +259
```

I tried to add in the appSettings of the web.config:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
```

But, it didn't fix the problem...

The weird thing is, I get the error only when my site is in production on IIS (I don't get the error while debugging with the ASP.NET Development Server).

And, recently we added a ssl certificate to my website in IIS, is it possible the certificates cause the problem ?

Comment: Do you get the same result locally with IIS Express?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Oh, ok sorry, yes my bad (bad habbit) Thank you for the edit :)

Comment: "The URL-encoded form data is not valid." sounds like... your form data is invalid. Are you using a webfarm with several servers with different machine keys?

Comment: How many key/value pairs are being posted back?  Are any of the keys HTML content?

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys. Im gonna answer all your questions tomorrow. The day is finished, and Ive been busy with support all PM. Thank you !